# Get ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in core console app in container

Tags: asp.net-core, kubernetes, containers

I've a ASP.NET core console application that I run in a container on Kubernetes. In the deployment.yaml I've set the environment variable:

```
env:
   - name: "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"
     value: "Development"
```

And in the console application I've the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
 {
            Console.WriteLine("Env: " + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"));
 }
```

But the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is empty, how can I get to the configured environment variable? I use the same steps in a core webapi project and there I get the variable as follow:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
     env.EnvironmentName
}
```

This works in the core webapi but I don't have IHostingEnvironment in the console app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've kind of found the 'reason' I guess. I wanted to read the "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in the "static Program()" method, there it was empty. But when I do the same in the "void Main(string[] args)" method it is set and it works as expected.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We use this template to run a ASP.NET Core App in our Kubernetes cluster:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: <namespace>
  name: <application name>
spec:
  replicas: 1
  minReadySeconds: 15
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: <app-label>
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: <container-name>
          image: <image-name>
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          env:
            - name: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
              value: "Release"
```

Comment: That is the same as I've done, except the extra " around ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT. I've tried without it and there was nog difference. Do you use this deploy script with an asp.net core console application?

Comment: This configuration is used to  deploy an ASP.NET Core MVC application.


What happens when you start your Container image with `docker run -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Release <image-name>`? Do you see the output of the environment variable?

Comment: then is does work indeed. But I don't use that run command, guess Kubernetes does that internally?

Comment: No, but it means that you program works correctly. But then it should work in Kubernetes too, if your configuration looks like mine above.

Comment: This answer helped me so that I could edit my deployment file correctly to use development environment.